# getting a table's column name without constraints in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, how can i get SQL table column names only belongs to that table i.e without its foreign key constraints?

Here is my model:

```
 public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeQualification> EmployeeQualifications { get; set; }
```

I have used the below snippet to get the column names but it returns all the properties in Model

```
var names = typeof(EmployeeMaster).GetProperties()
                    .Select(property => property.Name)
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var names = typeof(EmployeeMaster).GetProperties()
              .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsValueType || x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
              .Select(property => property.Name)
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: keep in mind that this will ignore all mappings, so your table might as well look entirely different.